# How to avoid the start up screen message?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I start `screen`, I get the following message:

```
Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06

Copyright (c) 1993-2002 Juergen Weigert, Michael Schroeder
Copyright (c) 1987 Oliver Laumann

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
Free Software Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program (see the file COPYING); if not, write to the Free
Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.

Send bugreports, fixes, enhancements, t-shirts, money, beer & pizza to screen@uni-erlangen.de

To use byobu (formerly screen-profiles), exit screen and run 'byobu'.

[Press Space or Return to end.]
```

How can I skip over this message and avoid typing an extra key every time I start `screen`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is controlled by these two options:

> ```
>  license
>  Display the disclaimer page. This is done whenever screen is started without options,
>  which should be often enough. See also the "startup_message" command.
> ```

and

> ```
>  startup_message on|off
>  Select whether you want to see the copyright notice during startup.  Default is `on',
>  as you probably noticed.
> ```

The latter accepts a boolean value:

```
$ grep startup_message .screenrc
  startup_message off
```

Both are documented in the [`screen(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) manpage.